# C# Regular Expression for String matching

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am looking for a regular expression that returns success only if the input string contains following characters:

```
a-zA-Z0-9~!@$^ ()_-+’:.?
```

Is this regular expression correct?

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9~!@$^ ()_-+’:.?]+$
```

I have understood what `^` means here but not sure about `+$`. Also are there any alternatives to this? By the way the above regular expression also includes a space character between ^ and (

Comment: thanks. i just need to ensure that before the input string is passed onto a service, it only contains the characters listed above. it shouldn't contain any other character.

Comment: You can use \w as a short hand for [a-zA-Z_0-9] in .Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, but get rid of that dash in the middle of your character class and put it at the beginning:

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9~!@$^ ()_+’:.?]+$
```

And make sure when you put it in a string that you use the proper string qualifier (I forget what it's called):

```
@"^[-a-zA-Z0-9~!@$^ ()_+’:.?]+$"
```

As to whether or not you can do it in other ways, sure, for example a negative look-ahead that doesn't actually match anything. I don't think a proper regex optimizer would leave one better than the other, it's just a matter of preference. Do you want something that looks to succeed (selects the entire string if valid), or something that looks to fail (negative look-ahead).

Honestly if performance is at all important, you should write a good old `for` and loop over the characters (or the equivalent LINQ implementation). Regex won't even be in the ballpark.

Answer (score 2):

> it only contains the characters listed above

```
bool invalidCharsExist = 
     Regex.Replace(input, @"[a-zA-Z0-9~!@\$\^\ \(\)_\-\+’:\.\?]", "").Length != 0;
```

BTW: This is not fully equivalent to your regex (It will also include non-ascii letters and digits) but I think it is a better way to check

```
var specialChars = new HashSet<char>("~!@$^ ()_-+’:.?");
var allValid  = input.All(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || specialChars.Contains(c));
```

Answer (score 1):

the regular expression would be: `^[a-zA-Z0-9~!@$^ ()_\-+’:.?]+$`

I personally recommend using https://regex101.com to check regex expressions - note that they don't have C# support, but in general javascript's `RegExp` has similar syntax to  C#, but what it does give you a particularly useful explaination of what your expression is doing, here is this epression's explaination from there:

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9~!@$^ ()_\-\+’:.?]+` match a single character present in the list below

  - Quantifier: `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
  - `a-z` a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
  - `A-Z` a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
  - `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9
  - `~!@$^ ()_` a single character in the list `~!@$^ ()_` literally
  - `\-` matches the character `-` literally
  - `+’:.?` a single character in the list `’:.?` literally
- `$` assert position at end of the string

the issue with what you put in the OP was literally only forgetting to escape the `-` as it is reserved in the regular expression pattern to be used for special purposes (i.e in the `[]` notation the `-` is reserved to declare a character range like `a-z`)